# Confusion over 診せたところ

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension

> カピバラのオスの鼻には「モリージョ」という突起物があるのが特徴で、獣医師に**診せたところ**、バァラはオスだと確認されたということです。
>   The male capybara has a feature known as a モリージョ on its nose, and it was confirmed that it was a male *during examination by a vet*

I'm not at all sure about the 診せたところ part. I can only find the verb 診る in dictionaries. I'm assuming it's a fancy way of writing 見せる. So 獣医師に診せた would be "shown to a vet"?

I'm also confused by how ところ works here. I understand that a verb in past tense + ところ means that the verb has just been completed, but the whole thing is a noun phrase and I don't understand how it fits into the grammar here.

Maybe I'm overthinking it. Can I add に onto the end and get:

> 獣医師に診せたところに...
>   At the point in time that it was shown to a vet ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「Verb (usually in past tense) + ところ」

means:

> "upon (verb)ing"

Thus, 「獣医師{じゅういし}に診{み}せたところ」 means "***upon showing it to the vet***".

「診る」 = "to examine"

「診せる」 = "to let (a doc) examine"

Lastly, you cannot say 「獣医師に診せたところ**に**」 because that will mean something else.  That will mean "***Just when*** I showed it to the vet".